# A cube appears when I generate a skin

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh, modifiers, vertices

Consider:

[image]

I’m trying to make a tree model, but when I generate a skin a cube appears. I tried redoing it, but it didn’t work.

Comment: Hello, maybe you have floating vertices? Could you please share your file?

Comment: How do i share my file

Comment: Read the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.com/ or use another platform like workupload and share the link

Comment: https://workupload.com/file/gRUpznwvABM

this?

Answer (score 4):

In *Edit* mode, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to see with transparency, and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to unhide this pixel, remove it:

[image]